# pine script - custom session breakout issue

Tags: session, pine-script, breakout

```
//@version=4
study("custom Session breakout", overlay=true)
my_session = input("1145-1215", type=input.session, title='Custom Session')


// Determine if we are in a session
// ----------------------------------
in_session = time(timeframe.period, my_session)
is_new_session(res, sess) =>
    t = time(res, sess)
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

new_session = is_new_session("1400", my_session)

// Get the High/Low of the EMA for the session
highH = float(na)
lowH = float(na)

highH := new_session ? close : in_session ? max(high , highH[1]) : high
lowH := new_session ? close : in_session ? min(low, lowH[1]) : low

plot(highH, color=color.green , style=plot.style_circles, title='High')
plot(lowH, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles, title='Low')
```

above the code I have written(help from https://www.pinecoders.com/) but It do not draw breakout lines on our custom session. Any help will be appreciated.

Image URL -
https://prnt.sc/tzpiff

Wrong candle marking issue -  https://prnt.sc/tzzwdj

Updated the code with alertcondition - Code below

```
//@version=4
study("custom Session breakout", overlay=true)
my_session = input("0945-1015", type=input.session, title='Custom Session')

is_new_session(res, sess) =>
    t = time(res, sess)
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

f_tickFormat() =>
    _s = tostring(syminfo.mintick)
    _s := str.replace_all(_s, "25", "00")
    _s := str.replace_all(_s, "5",  "0")
    _s := str.replace_all(_s, "1",  "0")

new_session  = is_new_session("1400", my_session)
var hiLine   = line.new(bar_index, high, bar_index, high, color = color.orange, width = 2, extend = extend.both)
var loLine   = line.new(bar_index, low,  bar_index, low,  color = color.orange, width = 2, extend = extend.both)
var hiLabel  = label.new(bar_index, na, "", color = color(na), style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.silver)
var loLabel  = label.new(bar_index, na, "", color = color(na), style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.silver)
var float hi = na
var float lo = na
if new_session
    // Update hi and lo.
    hi := high
    lo := low
    // Update lines.
    line.set_xy1(  hiLine,  bar_index - 1, hi)   
    line.set_xy2(  hiLine,  bar_index, hi)   
    line.set_xy1(  loLine,  bar_index - 1, lo)   
    line.set_xy2(  loLine,  bar_index, lo)
    // Update labels.
    label.set_xy(  hiLabel, bar_index, hi)
    label.set_text(hiLabel, tostring(hi, f_tickFormat()))
    label.set_xy(  loLabel, bar_index, lo)
    label.set_text(loLabel, tostring(lo, f_tickFormat()))

// Crosses
xUp = crossover( close, hi)
xDn = crossunder(close, lo)

//Alert
alertcondition(xUp, title='Up Breakout', message='Up Breakout')
alertcondition(xDn, title='Down Breakout', message='Down Breakout')


// Mark session beginnings for debugging.
plotchar(new_session, "new_session", "•", location.abovebar, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(xUp, "xUp", "▲", location.belowbar, color.lime, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(xDn, "xDn", "▼", location.abovebar, color.fuchsia, size = size.tiny)
```

Note - I have added alert condition in pinescript and also set alert in TradingView but alert is not activated on time i.e. the breakout of HIGH/LOW.

Comment: Would help if you showed a chart with the lines you are looking for. "breakout lines" can mean lots of different things.

Comment: Thanks. I have added chart image url at below of the description.

Answer (score 0):

#### Version 1

This will draw lines at the high and low of the last session's first bar and show the price on it. The idea is we draw a first, useless line and label, then adjust it when we find a new session beginning. If you need to change colors, change them in the variable declarations before the `if` statement.

The `f_tickformat()` thing formats the price's decimals with the tick precision of the chart's symbol.

```
//@version=4
study("custom Session breakout", overlay=true)
my_session = input("1145-1215", type=input.session, title='Custom Session')

is_new_session(res, sess) =>
    t = time(res, sess)
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

f_tickFormat() =>
    _s = tostring(syminfo.mintick)
    _s := str.replace_all(_s, "25", "00")
    _s := str.replace_all(_s, "5",  "0")
    _s := str.replace_all(_s, "1",  "0")

new_session = is_new_session("1400", my_session)
var hiLine  = line.new(bar_index, high, bar_index, high, color = color.orange, width = 2, extend = extend.both)
var loLine  = line.new(bar_index, low,  bar_index, low,  color = color.orange, width = 2, extend = extend.both)
var hiLabel = label.new(bar_index, na, "", color = color(na), style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.silver)
var loLabel = label.new(bar_index, na, "", color = color(na), style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.silver)
if new_session
    // Update lines.
    line.set_xy1(  hiLine,  bar_index - 1, high)   
    line.set_xy2(  hiLine,  bar_index, high)   
    line.set_xy1(  loLine,  bar_index - 1, low)   
    line.set_xy2(  loLine,  bar_index, low)
    // Update labels.
    label.set_xy(  hiLabel, bar_index, high)
    label.set_text(hiLabel, tostring(high, f_tickFormat()))
    label.set_xy(  loLabel, bar_index, low)
    label.set_text(loLabel, tostring(low, f_tickFormat()))

// Mark session beginnings for debugging.
plotchar(new_session, "new_session", "•", location.abovebar, size = size.tiny)
```

[image]

#### Version 2

This will show markers on crosses of the levels. You can use the same condition to define your alerts using `alertcondition()`:

```
//@version=4
study("custom Session breakout", overlay=true)
my_session = input("1145-1215", type=input.session, title='Custom Session')

is_new_session(res, sess) =>
    t = time(res, sess)
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

f_tickFormat() =>
    _s = tostring(syminfo.mintick)
    _s := str.replace_all(_s, "25", "00")
    _s := str.replace_all(_s, "5",  "0")
    _s := str.replace_all(_s, "1",  "0")

new_session  = is_new_session("1400", my_session)
var hiLine   = line.new(bar_index, high, bar_index, high, color = color.orange, width = 2, extend = extend.both)
var loLine   = line.new(bar_index, low,  bar_index, low,  color = color.orange, width = 2, extend = extend.both)
var hiLabel  = label.new(bar_index, na, "", color = color(na), style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.silver)
var loLabel  = label.new(bar_index, na, "", color = color(na), style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.silver)
var float hi = na
var float lo = na
if new_session
    // Update hi and lo.
    hi := high
    lo := low
    // Update lines.
    line.set_xy1(  hiLine,  bar_index - 1, hi)   
    line.set_xy2(  hiLine,  bar_index, hi)   
    line.set_xy1(  loLine,  bar_index - 1, lo)   
    line.set_xy2(  loLine,  bar_index, lo)
    // Update labels.
    label.set_xy(  hiLabel, bar_index, hi)
    label.set_text(hiLabel, tostring(hi, f_tickFormat()))
    label.set_xy(  loLabel, bar_index, lo)
    label.set_text(loLabel, tostring(lo, f_tickFormat()))

// Crosses
xUp = crossover( close, hi)
xDn = crossunder(close, lo)

// Mark session beginnings for debugging.
plotchar(new_session, "new_session", "•", location.abovebar, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(xUp, "xUp", "▲", location.belowbar, color.lime, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(xDn, "xDn", "▼", location.abovebar, color.fuchsia, size = size.tiny)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will try by myself to add alert on line breakouts i.e. alert on High/low breakout. You are a great help PineCoders-LucF

Comment: If have tried using pinescript alert conditions syntax but when I was creating alert in TV, it gave me repaint issue dialog box. What I need is that whenever the price breaks the HIGH or LOW(after custom session completion) TV should generate alert. Thanks I am learning with you

Comment: Thanks you!! you are so fast PineCoders-LucF. You are excellent programmer.

Comment: @ PineCoders-LucF I have added alert conditions but it is not alerting when crossover occurs. Please see.

Comment: First, we won't write the complete indicator for you. We provided you with condition code so all you have to do is configure your alerts with `alertcondition()`. Second, if something doesn't work and you don't provide the code that's not working, we can't fix it.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience happened to you. I have added the pinescript codes in description's bottom. Thanks